# path-connected subgroup of Lie group is Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

**Theorem (Yamabe)**: Let $G$ be a Lie group, and let $H$ be an arc-wise connected subgroup of $G$.Then $H$ is a Lie subgroup of $G$.

I am reading this theory form an appendix in a book called (bilinear control systems, Elliott) hence there is no enough details about proofs.. But for this theorem there was a discussion instead of a proof, which I need help to understand initially for the matrix Lie groups case.

Here is the discussion: Let $G$ be a (real) matrix Lie group and $H$ be an arc-wise connected subgroup of $G$. Let $\mathfrak{h}$ be the set of $n \times n$ matrices $L$ with property that for any neighborhood $U$ of the identity matrix in $G$, there exists an arc $\alpha: [0,1] \rightarrow H$ s.t $\alpha(0)=I,\alpha(t)\in e^{tL}U , 0\leq t\leq 1$. First show that if $X\in \mathfrak{h}$ then so does $\lambda X$, $\lambda \in\mathbb{R}$. Use (Lie product theorem) to show that for sufficiently small $X$ and $Y$, $X+Y \in \mathfrak{h}$. Therefore $\mathfrak{h}$ is a matrix Lie algebra. Use the *Brouwer fixed point theorem* to show that $H$ is the connected matrix Lie subgroup of $G$ that corresponds to $\mathfrak{h}$.

You can use another notations and symbols if you wish. Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4):

I found a proof on page 354 of [Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups (Hilgert and Neeb)](http://books.google.com/books?id=PYWoqskGw1YC&pg=PA347&lpg=PA347&dq=yamabes%20theorem%20lie%20subalgebra&source=bl&ots=N3Fc3JAkUA&sig=qfZJVW0C3RdOIKavelY2c_E1oFo&hl=en&sa=X&ei=u_avUemdPPO00QGihIH4DQ&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=yamabes%20theorem%20lie%20subalgebra&f=false)
 with a free google preview. It uses the Brouwer fixed point theorem, and $A(H)$ is the sub algebra you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, all that need to be verified is that $H$ is a (differentiable) manifold. But as $G$ is a manifold, any (arcwise) connected component of $G$ is also a manifold.

Comment: How do we know that $H$ is a whole connected component of $G$?