# The list of connected subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: lie-groups

So, the question is to find all connected subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$. I understand, how to find all closed connected subgroups: they are in one-to-one correspondence with Lie subalgebras of $\mathfrak{sl}(2,\mathbb{R})$. Up to conjugation, they are: orthogonal, diagonal, upper triangular and upper unitriangular matrices. I also know, how to find all path-connected subgroups: the list is the same as in the case of closed subgroups. But I don't know, whether or not it exhausts all connected subgroups.

EDIT: To clarify, the question can be formulated, as whether it is true, that for subgroups of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ connectedness and path-connectedness is the same property.

Comment: Have you already checked this ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646183/list-of-connected-lie-subgroups-of-mathrmsl2-mathbbc?rq=1 It can give some insight

Comment: Yes, but I think in that question they only consider closed connected subgroups. And I'm interested in all connected subgroups

Comment: Yes you're right, this is way too restrictive

Comment: Sometimes people say "connected subgroups" and mean "connected Lie subgroups". See for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2822072/connected-subgroups-of-sl2-mathbbr). Why are you interested in the non-closed subgroups?

Comment: @DietrichBurde, No, I mean precisely connected subgroups, not connected Lie subgroups. That's the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is related to the existence of connected but not path-connected subgroups of $SL_2(\Bbb R)$. I am not sure that there exists a list of all connected subgroups of $SL_2(\Bbb R)$. But it seems that one example showing that connectedness and path-connectedness is not the same property for subgroups of Lie groups is enough (see your edit). There is already a long discussion about the construction of connected, not path-connected subgroups of Lie groups [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895441/connected-not-path-connected-subgroup-of-mathbbt2), with links to MO-posts. The construction is given for the $2$-torus. A similar construction could work for $SL_2(\Bbb R)$.

The answer given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1895441/connected-not-path-connected-subgroup-of-mathbbt2) mentiones a [*Theorem by Thomas*](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ijm/1256063578):

**Theorem (Thomas):** Every Lie group of dimension greater than one always admits a connected subgroup which is not a Lie subgroup (and hence isn't path connected, since connected Lie subgroups are path-connected).

However, it is not clear if the proof is entirely correct.
Moreover, his definition of a Lie subgroup is different from other definitions (Thomas calls it an "analytic" subgroup).

Comment: It is not true, that path-connected subgroups of Lie group are closed, as shown by the example of irrational winding of a 2-torus. It is not closed because the closure of this irrational winding is the whole torus.

Comment: I see. But at least the result of Yamabe (1950) states that every arcwise connected subgroup of a real Lie group is Lie subgroup. For $G=SL_2(\Bbb R)$ this should be the same as path-connected.

Comment: The title [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/405202/path-connected-subgroup-of-lie-group-is-lie-group) is confusing. In fact, arcwise connected is assumed. In the first answer a link to a book by Hilgert and Neeb is given. There is more about connected and path-connected subgroups of Lie groups (which might be useful, I haven't checked yet).